# Passing string parameters from c to assembly x86

Tags: c, string, assembly, x86

So I am trying to ask for and receive input for 2 separate strings.  Right now they are a max of 30 and ending in a newline character.  Yes I know about the whole thing with don't use fgets(), but it works great for what I am trying to do.

Anyways, with these 2 strings I want to call an assembly function that calculates if string 1 is "greater than" string 2.  I have done this in assembly itself and it worked fine, but trying to get it from a c file is not working correctly.  I imagine this is because I am not loading the strings into registers correctly.  Here is the code from the two files:

stringgt.asm:

```
global  stringgt

SECTION .text

stringgt:

    push    ebp                      ; setting upstack frame
    mov     ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp+8]     ; eax = start of string c
    mov ecx, [ebp+12]        ; ecx = start of string d
    push edx

    xor edx, edx ; index edx = 0
    cld

top:
    mov al, [eax + edx]   ;comparing first element of two strings
    cmp [ecx + edx], al
    jb output_true       ; jump to output_true if first is greater
    ja output_false      ; jump to output_false if second is greater
    cmp al, 10           ; checking for newline
    je output_false      ; if newline, then they are either equal or 2nd is greater
                         ; therefore first is not greater output false
    inc edx              ; increment index
    jmp top              ; back to start of loop

output_true:
    mov   eax, 1                 ; eax = 1, eax is return value
    jmp exit                 ; exit

output_false:
    mov   eax, 0                 ; eax = 0, eax is return value

exit:
    pop edx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Now string.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int stringgt(char* s1, char* s2);

int main()
{
  char* c;
  char* d;
  printf("Type first string: ");
  fgets(c, 30, stdin);
  printf("Type second string: ");
  fgets(d, 30, stdin);
  int i = stringgt(c, d);
  if (i != 0)
  {
    printf("True\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("False\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The issue seems to be its returning false on pretty much everything.  I do think I am loading the strings into eax and ecx incorrectly, perhaps the 2nd string is not located at ebp+12 but somewhere else?

Comment: You are using `fgets` wrong. You realize it needs a buffer, right? Change `char* c` to `char c[30]` and similarly for `d`. With that, it seems to work here.

Comment: `c` and `d` are pointing no nowhere. Declare them as `char c[30]; char d[30]`

Comment: Hmm... yeah thats a silly mistake. Works now thanks

Comment: There’s no problem with using fgets, by the way. gets is the one  that should be banned, because it doesn’t have a buffer size parameter.

Comment: A couple comments on your assembly code: 1) it doesn’t need to save and restore edx. 2) it doesn’t need to cld, because it doesn’t use any instructions that depend on the direction flag. 3) you can’t use eax for both the pointer to the first string and to hold each character as you compare it. (al is the low byte of eax.)